# Want to eliminate the automatic time stamp of pdflatex (or lyx?)

Tags: pdftex, lyx

Whenever I create a document with lyx, and if there is title and author in the document, today's time is automatically put in the document.

For example, if I pdf-fy the following code by WinEdt, or in lyx, the outcome is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2iKVlLwpjaNTNhS3drWFBPTEE/edit?usp=sharing

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```

What's the code to remove that time stamp from the output document?

Comment: Is your goal to get a binary-identical output file every time? There's internal timestamps that `pdflatex` creates that would need to be disabled, too.

Comment: You could try setting a date explicitly using `\date{}` before calling `\maketitle`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz What's "binary-identical"? My goal is to not see the time stamp in my document.

Comment: @Jakob Thank you but my goal is to eliminate the time stamp rather than to change it to another date.

Comment: @user2604484 have you tried `\date{}` without an argument? This should exclude the date (see here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation).

Comment: @user2604484: I don't think there is an automatic provision to re-gain the "empty line" that an empty date would create.

Comment: @Jakob This was perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

To answer this question explicitly (not only via comments)...

Use the plain `\date{}` command before calling `maketitle`. This excludes the date line from the titlepage as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation).

If, for whatever reason, you require the date line to be blank but present, you could use a invisible date e.g. with `\date{\phantom{x}}`.

Thus, the complete minimal example would be

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\maketitle
test
\end{document}
```